# Why does a question mark in a dataframe column title show as a period when outputting from r to an excel sheet (using xlsx package)?

Tags: r, xlsx, r-xlsx

Suppose I use the xlsx package to write a dataframe from r to excel.  And suppose I have a dataframe with a column title that includes a question mark (code below):

```
library(xlsx)
rm(list = ls())

fpath <- "whatever filepath"

#My df
df <- data.frame("Questions?" = c("bla", "bla bla"), "123Numbers"= c(1,2))

#Now output 
wb <- createWorkbook()
sh <- createSheet(wb, sheetName = "Bla")
addDataFrame(df, sh)

saveWorkbook(wb, paste0(fpath,".xlsx"))
```

When I open the excel output file, I get the following:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5qmh.png)

1. Why does the question mark show up as a period in the Questions column title?
2. Why is there a random "X" character in front of the 123Numbers column title?

Of course, if there is an easy fix to this that I am missing, please advise.  Thanks!

Comment: You can use `check.names = FALSE` in `data.frame` i.e. `df <- data.frame("Questions?" = c("bla", "bla bla"), "123Numbers"= c(1,2), check.names = FALSE)`

Comment: works perfectly.  I never used check.names before so I'll look that up, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `check.names` argument is by default `TRUE` in `data.frame` and it would make sure that all the non-standard column names are modified by applied (`make.names`-> `make.unique`). If we specify it as `FALSE`, the column names would not get changed

```
df <- data.frame("Questions?" = c("bla", "bla bla"),
    "123Numbers"= c(1,2), check.names = FALSE)
```